# How to check if record is already exists and then update or insert in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to check first if data already exists or not. If data already exists, then update function otherwise insert a new record.
It's working when inserting a new record, but I don't want to be duplicate rows in future.

```html
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->all();
        
            $jobseeker = new Jobseeker();
            $jobseeker->fullname= $requestData['full name'];
            $jobseeker->gender= $requestData['Gender'];
            $jobseeker->messenger_user_id= $request->{'messenger user id'};
            $jobseeker->save();
    }
```

Here is how I tried, I check if the messenger user id already exists or not, if messenger user id already exists I want to update the existing row, otherwise I want to insert a new row.

```html
    public function store(Request $request,$messenger_user_id)
    {
        $requestData = $request->all();

        $my_msg_id = Jobseeker::where('messenger_user_id',$requestData['messenger user id'])->first();
        
        if (is_null($my_msg_id)) {
          $jobseekers = Jobseeker::find($messenger_user_id);
          $jobseeker->fullname= $requestData['full name'];
          $jobseeker->gender= $requestData['Gender'];
          $jobseeker->messenger_user_id= $request->{'messenger user id'};
        }
        else{
            $jobseeker = new Jobseeker();
            $jobseeker->fullname= $requestData['full name'];
            $jobseeker->gender= $requestData['Gender'];
            $jobseeker->messenger_user_id= $request->{'messenger user id'};
            $jobseeker->save();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you heard firstOrCreate/ firstOrNew methods in laravel ? See docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserts

Comment: hi, yeah i heard before, why?

Comment: Then it's better to use those methods for your problem

Comment: firstOrCreate([], []) method will do the job.. it takes 2 parameters , first is the array of field you want to query ( where parameters ) and second is the array of data you want to insert.. so basically if no row exists it will create a new row else it will update the row..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do all of this yourself in laravel. Use the method `firstOrCreate`.

```
$data_array = [
    'full_name' => $requestData['full name'],
    'gender' => $requestData['Gender'],
];

$jobseeker = App\Jobseeker::firstOrCreate(['messenger_user_id' => $messenger_user_id], $data_array);
```

It takes an array as first parameter to find a model and array as a second parameter to update the record with given key-values in that array or it'll create a new record with given data, then returns the model object.

Comment: If someone could kindly tell me what happens when we have a batch array to insert or update, it works well with a single record.